# Monthly Hall of Fame Answers & Questions

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, voting

I'm wondering, why SO don't add a special function that gathers answers and questions which have the higher upvotes and create a some kind of a monthly pdf to which users can subscribe and receive by mail or simply download it.

The fact that almost (I'll say 80%) of programming questions top ten results in Google points to SO website shouldn't be ignored, and such a feature can be developed to become even a magazine.

This feature can select top used tags for current month, top questions and top answers, or simply adding a "Vote for Top-of-Month" button on which specific previliged users (maybe 500+ reputation ?) can click and then do a little comparison between programmatically chosen QA and TopofMonth votes and autoselect those in both lists. What do you think of it ?

Comment: I'm really curious about it, why a PDF? IMHO, I don't see any advantage on this feature being on this format... Also, please prefer to [edit] your question to add arguments/details about your proposal/question; I'm saying this because of your comment to Bradley's answer: `I'm talking about something else...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=month

Answer (score 3):

We already have something like this. Just subscribe to the newsletter of your favorite sites:

https://stackexchange.com/newsletters

Its weekly, not monthly, but I don't see much benefit in creating a whole new thing just to modify that.

Comment: Newsletter with PDF isn't same as Newsletter, and the current newsletter don't have the "TOP" feature which is the main advantage of what I propose.

Comment: @ChaibiAlaa Did you look at the preview? It had a "top new questions" section.

Comment: Yes I'm talking about something else, like the best of the new with a different selection method